# jQuery .on Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and I am having some trouble getting this code to work:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on ({
        'mouseenter' : { /////// PROBLEMS!
            '.nav' : function () {
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', .50);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that with the nav class. I'm guessing I'm not specifying it as a child of the body element correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't get the syntax for `jQuery.on()`

[API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

So.. in your example, you're passing to `jQuery.on()` just one argument: an object with one key ("mouseenter") and another object as it's value.

The correct syntax in your case should be something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on ('mouseenter', '.nav', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', .50);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps...

---

**[Edit]** Based in @jfriend00's comment below, here's an alternative that looks more like the OP question (although I think first option is more clear)

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on ({
        'mouseenter': function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', .50);
        }
    }, '.nav');
});
```

Comment: There is a version of `.on()` that [accepts an object for the first argument](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data), but the OP is not using it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.nav', function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```